# Función para hacer un bucle for anidado en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Es posible utilizar una ***función recursiva*** para hacer bucles *for anidados*, he probado muchas cosas pero todas me daban algún error.

```js
for (let a of p) {
   for (let a of p) { 
    for (let a of p) {    
      for (let a of p) {   
        for (let a of p) {       
          for (let a of p) {    
            for (let a of p) {            
              for (let a of p) {                
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Reducirlo a: 
function rep() {
  for (let a of p) {
    rep();
  }
}

for (let a of p) {
  rep();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la recursividad sin problemas. En este ejemplo que te pongo recorres el array `p` tantas veces como indique la condición de salida (en este caso sería que hayas contado 10 ovejas) y llamando a la misma función `rep()`:

```js
let p = ['', '', '', ''];
let i = 1;
// Reducirlo a: 
function rep() {
  for (let a of p) {    
    if(a===''){      
      if(i<=10){
        console.log(`${i}: ${a} - ¡Beeeeeeeee!`);
        i++;
        rep();
      }
      else{
        console.log('ZzZzZzZzZz');
      }
    }
  }  
}

rep();
```

Es importante controlar bien la condición de salida para no provocar bucles infinitos... y tener así dulces sueños :)